# Set individual auto-repeat rate for each key

Tags: linux, x11, usb, keyboard, xkb

On X11, doing something like

```
xset r rate 120 240
```

it's possible to set the repeat rate for the entire keyboard.

But I wonder if it's possible to do the same thing for each individual key? (Ie. to have different keys have different repeat rates.)

Perhaps using some obscure XKB configuration, or the XKB C API, or some evdev/ioctl hack?

And, if not, how could you could do this if you have access to the keyboard firmware and can control the USB HID code that the keyboard sends?

I know this must be possible *somehow* because the modifier keys seem to have a zero repeat rate, while the rest of the keys have a non-zero repeat rate.

---

One idea that comes to mind is to register different sets of keys as different USB devices, and then set different repeat rates for different devices, if that can be done at the USB level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be possible without some serious effort.

I'm not sure of all the differences between PS/2 and USB keyboard communication protocols, but I imagine that they're likely pretty similar in the way that they operate. Given that assumption, what you're trying to do is not really possible at the hardware level and would be pretty difficult to do at the OS level.

At the hardware level, the problem is that the auto-repeat rate is set by [sending a command](https://wiki.osdev.org/PS/2_Keyboard#Commands) to the keyboard and that command applies to all repeating keys. There is no command to set the repeat rate for individual keys.

At the OS level, you'd have to rewrite the keyboard input handler, which is either directly part of the kernel or a driver that gets loaded into the kernel. The keyboard sends an interrupt for every key press and key release, but it also sends an interrupt for each time the key auto-repeats when held down. So the driver would need to ignore the repeated key interrupts and artificially generate keypress events at the desired rate for that key until a key-release interrupt is received.

Alternatively, you could make code changes to Xorg to implement this functionality at the user level.

Answer (score 1):

The X11 keyboard model does not support multiple key repeat rates.

When a key is pressed and released, the application receives a keypress and keyrelease event.  If the key is held and the key is not a modifier, it would get multiple keypress events before the keyrelease.

Modifier keys are handled differently.  While the application does get a keypress and keyrelease event for a modifier (with as you say, no repeat), usually these are ignored and instead the application looks at the modifier bitmask that is attached to all other keypresses.  In other words, the modifier key states are attached to every keypress for non-modifier keys.

Modifier keys don't have a different repeat rate -- they don't support repeat at all.

Since the application gets key events, if you want different repeat rates for different keys within an application, it would be possible to just have the application simulate any rate you want until it gets a keyrelease event.

Comment: Exactly, not supporting repeat at all means that **there is** a way to discriminate the repeat behavior of different (sets of) keys.